# Moving objects inside a list, colliding with player

Tags: c#, list, xna, collision

I had recently asked the question about how they should collide with a tile map and had an answer that I was unable to do in my game because of the time constraints, I improvised and got it to work. But now I am moving on to another issue that had come up when coding which is that all of a sudden my platforms stop colliding with the player. One second they could the next they did not.

I looked and saw no difference in how the platforms were to interact with the player yet some how it just does not work. I am beside myself with how they could happen.

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061397/moving-platforms-in-a-tile-map)** is the last post about how they collide with a tile.

**[Here](https://mega.co.nz/#!20xghSxQ!hFzz_2j8oST7cvyoDytyzhUDUw5eWePZe7zvbZbzslM)** is the link to the project if you just want to look at this pile of garbage code.

I use three class to have the platforms moving, the main class Game1, MovingPlatform, and Block. Game1 runs all of it, the MovingPlatform helps the list and makes the platforms tick and the Block helps with collision with tiles.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong that is making the platforms not collide?

I will start with the MovingPlatform Class:

```
public class MovingPlatform
{
    Game1 game1;

    public Texture2D Texture;
    public Vector2 Velocity;
    public Vector2 Position;
    public Rectangle Size;
    public Rectangle World;
    public float Speed;
    public bool Up;
    public bool Thing;
    float Time;

    public MovingPlatform(Texture2D Texture, Vector2 Position,float Speed, bool Up)
    {
        this.Texture = Texture;
        this.Position = Position;
        this.Speed = Speed;
        this.Up = Up;
        Thing = true;
        Velocity = Vector2.Zero;
        Size = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, 50, 25);
    }

    public void Initialize(Game1 game1)
    {
        this.game1 = game1;

    }

    public Player BlockCollision(Player player)
    {
        Rectangle top = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + 5, (int)Position.Y - 10, Size.Width - 10, 10);
        Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + 5, (int)Position.Y + Size.Height, Size.Width - 10, 10);
        Rectangle left = new Rectangle((int)Position.X - 10, (int)Position.Y + 5, 10, Size.Height - 10);
        Rectangle right = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + Size.Width, (int)Position.Y + 5, 10, Size.Height - 10);

        if (!player.goingUp)
        {
            if (top.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X, (int)player.Position.Y, player.Texture.Width, player.Texture.Height)))
            {
                if (player.Position.Y + player.Texture.Height > Position.Y && player.Position.Y + player.Texture.Height < Position.Y + Texture.Height / 2)
                {
                    player.Position.Y = player.ground = Position.Y - player.Texture.Height;
                    player.Velocity.Y = 0;
                    player.isJumping = false;
                    player.Time = 0;
                    player.botCollision = true;
                }

            }
            else if (player.isJumping == false && player.ground == Position.Y - player.Texture.Height)
            {
                player.isJumping = true;
                player.initialVelocity = 0;
            }

        }
        return player;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Time += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        World = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (Up == true)
        {
            if (Thing == true)
            {
                Position.Y -= 2;
            }
            else if (Thing == false)
            {
                Position.Y += 2;
            }
        }

        if (Up == false)
        {
            if (Thing == true)
            {
                Position.X -= 2;
            }
            else if (Thing == false)
            {
                Position.X += 2;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Size.Width, Size.Height), Color.White);
    }
}
}
```

Block:

```
public class Block
{
    Game1 game1;

    public Texture2D Texture;
    public Vector2 Position;
    public int BlockState;
    KeyboardState prevKB;
    KeyboardState kbState;
    public static bool NextLevel = false;
    Rectangle Contain;


    public Block(Texture2D Texture, Vector2 Position, int BlockState)
    {
        this.Texture = Texture;
        this.Position = Position;
        this.BlockState = BlockState;

        Contain = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, 50, 50);
    }

    public void Initialize(Game1 game1)
    {
        this.game1 = new Game1();
    }

    public Player BlockCollision(Player player, GameTime gameTime, Game1 game1)
    {
        this.game1 = game1;
        kbState = Keyboard.GetState();

        Rectangle BlockRectangle = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);

        Rectangle top = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + 5, (int)Position.Y - 10, Texture.Width - 10, 10);
        Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + 5, (int)Position.Y + Texture.Height, Texture.Width - 10, 10);
        Rectangle left = new Rectangle((int)Position.X - 10, (int)Position.Y + 5, 10, Texture.Height - 10);
        Rectangle right = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + Texture.Width, (int)Position.Y + 5, 10, Texture.Height - 10);

        if (BlockState > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < game1.Platforms.Count; i++)
            {
                if (top.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.X, (int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.Y, game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Width, game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Height)))
                {
                    game1.Platforms[i].Thing = true;
                }

                if (bottom.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.X, (int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.Y, game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Width, game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Height)))
                {
                    game1.Platforms[i].Thing = false;
                }

                if (left.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.X, (int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.Y, game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Width, game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Height)))
                {
                    game1.Platforms[i].Thing = false;
                }

                if (right.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.X, (int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.Y, game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Width, game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Height)))
                {
                    game1.Platforms[i].Thing = false;
                }
            }
        }
        prevKB = Keyboard.GetState();

        return player;
    }
```

Then Finally the Game1 Class:

```
    public List<Block> Blocks;
    public List<MovingPlatform> Platforms;

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        Blocks = new List<Block>();
        Platforms = new List<MovingPlatform>();

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        movingPlatform = new MovingPlatform(ballSprite, Vector2.Zero, 3.0f, true);
        movingPlatform.Initialize(this);
    }

    void LoadLevel(int level)
    {
        Blocks.Clear();
        Platforms.Clear();

        Texture2D platform = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Platform");

        for (int x = 0; x < tileWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < tileHeight; y++)
            {
                //Platform Stoper
                if (Levels[level][y, x] == '+')
                {
                    Blocks.Add(new Block(movingArea, new Vector2(x * 50, y * 50), 3));
                }
                //Vertical Moving Platform
                if (Levels[level][y, x] == '=')
                {
                    Platforms.Add(new MovingPlatform(platform, new Vector2(x * 50, y * 50), 3.0f, true));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (Block b in Blocks)
        {
            player = b.BlockCollision(player, gameTime, this);
        }

        foreach (MovingPlatform m in Platforms)
        {
            player = m.BlockCollision(player);
            m.Update(gameTime);
        }
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, null, camera.Transform());
        foreach (Block b in Blocks)
        {
            b.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        foreach (MovingPlatform m in Platforms)
        {
            m.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I think that it does "Work", but the player will fall through it so fast that the platform can't update and say "Hay, this player is falling and the platform should stop him".

Comment: i guess you are checking with box collision, add additional checking if player is under platform. like if bottom of player is under top of platform.

Comment: You should also get rid of the comparison checks. You never need == true or false in a Boolean comparison. It just slows things done as it first checks if the condition is true then it checks if true == true. To do false just use !bool.